# Не работают кнопки управления окном (свернуть, развернуть, закрыть)

Tags: windows-7, mfc, c++

Добрый всем день/вечер!
Есть MDI MFC проект, который разрабатывался сначала под Windows XP, а затем был перенесён на Windows 7 Max. В результате этого при работе с окном этого проекта не хотят работать эти три злосчастные кнопки. Проект просто виснет. 
Да, можно почистить реестр и всё сработает, но ровно до второго запуска проекта. Так же было замечено, что если отключить эффекты Aero, то кнопки работают как ни в чём не бывало. Может кто-то знает, где и что нужно допилить, чтобы и с Aero всё работало как надо? 
Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: А как Вы данный проект переносили?

Comment: Да просто на компе был XP - переставили на 7. Проект был сохранён на внешнем носителе на время переустановки. И это, кстати, касается не одного только этого конкретного компьютера. На всех остальных, на которых стоит 7 такая же проблема.

Comment: Вы знаете, я у Вас спросил: как Вы переносили - в том смысле, как компили и в какой "VS студии". Скажу откровенно, уже давно не занимаюсь VC++ + MFC - но "чуть - чуть" помню. Пока еще более грамотные программеры не подсказали, посмотрите: версию библиотеки MFC для Вашего проекта, создайте новый проект для Aero и - сравните код создания главного окна для Aero и традиционного окна (насколько помню, все там). А вообще, справка по MFC на сате "микрогибких - чтоб их Ж)". Удачи.

Comment: Извините, ступил) Проект всё время собирался только на VS 2010 SP 1 и сейчас этой традиции не изменил) Спасибо за советы!)

Comment: Вам спасибо за Спасибо. Но, скажу, я ОЧЕНЬ сильно удивлен - почему "сишники и плюсы" не ответили на Ваш вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак, как это обычно и бывает - вопрос решился собственными руками.
Дело всё было во "вражеском" тулбаре, который закрался в класс проекта CMainFrm ещё во времена, когда он начинал писаться в VS 2008. Странная всё-таки взаимосвязь между кнопками окна и тулбаром, но она есть. 
Так что вопрос всё-таки был в переносимости и некомпетентности того, кто начинал писать проект, а затем передал нам, и ничего не сказал о таких возможных проблемах.
Всем спасибо, вопрос можно закрывать!